# How to find out the "True" x ,y values of a view

Tags: iphone, uiview, screen, position

If I have a view inside another view, than its x,y values are relevant to its parent view.

I would like to know its x y position relative to the whole screen window-

that means 320 X 480 iphone screen window

The top left corner is 0,0 of course.

What is the way for getting its "True" x ,y values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use convertPoint:toView:, where the to view is the window property - although that isn't necessarily the screen, it usually will be.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code as not on my mac and can't remember the exact structure of the objects, but something along the lines of:

```
x = self.parentView.frame.x + self.frame.x;
y = self.parentView.frame.y + self.frame.y;
```

You could easily extend this to use a loop or recursion if the views are going to be more than one deep.

Comment: Note that frame coordinates won't work if a transform is applied to any of the views.